# Printing out a value from an object in an alert window

Tags: javascript, object, alert

I am trying to print out the name value of the person object in an alert window.

```
        var person ={};
        person = {
            name: 'Tray',
            distance_travelled: 0,
            say_name: alert(this.name),
        }

        person.say_name;
```

The result I am getting is an alert box that is empty.  When I hard code in the name the alert box prints correctly.  I tried say_name: alert(person.name), but that returns an undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a function to `say_name`. Right now you're invoking the function immediately and assigning its `undefined` return value. That's making `this` refer to something other than what you expect.

```js
var person = {
    name: 'Tray',
    distance_travelled: 0,
    say_name: function() {
        alert(this.name);
    },
}

person.say_name();
```

Now the `this` arg will refer to the `person` object because when you do `some_object.someMethod()`, the value of `this` in `someMethod()` gets automatically set to the `some_object` on which it was invoked.